# How to stop a specific Java process on Windows started using Task Scheduler?

Tags: java, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, batch-processing

I have a batch file, which runs a Java process. This batch file is scheduled for running at specific time using a windows Task Scheduler. The task is scheduled with following option selected "run even when user is logged or not".

I would like to stop the java process at a specific time. There are multiple Java processes on the system. So I cannot use `taskkill` with `/t /im (imagename)`. I tried using `taskill /t /fi (window title)` to stop. But this option works only when "run only when user is logged on" is selected for Java process. In my case the Java process needs to be run even when user is not logged on.

Can someone please guide me in how to stop the Java process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262231/obtaining-exitcode-using-start-process-and-waitforexit-instead-of-wait  Basically you start the process and set your code to end that process at the desired time.

Comment: I don't know what this question has to do with exit codes. In addition, I cannot find any mention of "killing a process at a desired time" (or something along those lines) anywhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can modify sources of that process:

   Add to it some thread, that with some frequency checks for existence of specific file (like, `.needsuicide`) and halts process if it exists, then create that file when you want to stop that process (don't forget to delete that file after process had killed itself).
2. If you have no acces to process sources:

   `grep` list of running `java` processes for matched command line parameters, like  `-jar "<name_of_desired_jar>"` (or any dummy parameter, like `omg_please_kill_me`, that you can specify in process scheduled task), then kill that process by his `pid`.
3. Combined approach, i.e., you have access to sources of that process, but want to `kill` it, not ask it to self-terminate

   On process start, let him create some empty file with specific name (like, `.kill_me_<pid-of-jvm-process>`, then if needed - look for that file and kill theprocess by specified `pid`.