# Determine if NUnit Tests are finished running in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, nunit, nunit-console

I can't seem to find a callback or a good way to determine if NUnit tests are finished running in a PowerShell script. I have come up with the solution below, but, it is not solid. Anyone have a better idea how how I would go about this?
 Or, maybe there is some black magic in NUnit I don't know about?
 Thanks in advance!

```
#SLN1: Could check TestResults.xml file length and loop until we're sure tests have ran
#- Then Send command to write to file in S3 Bucket. Then have server script check for a change to that bucket.


$NUNIT_EXE = "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe\"
$TESTING_DLL = "C:\CITestFramework\bin\Debug\CITESTS.dll"
#NUnit3 places test results where tests are ran from, so go local
$TESTING_RESULT_FILE = "TestResult.xml" 


Write-Host "Removing old test results."
If (Test-Path $TESTING_RESULT_FILE){
    Remove-Item $TESTING_RESULT_FILE
}


Write-Host "Starting Tests..."
$PROCESS = Start-Process $NUNIT_EXE $TESTING_DLL

$count = 0
$prev_size = 0
$wait = 5
Do{


    If (Test-Path $TESTING_RESULT_FILE){
        $file = Get-Item $TESTING_RESULT_FILE   
        Write-Host "Size:",$file.Length
        Write-Host "Prev Size:", $prev_size
        if($file.Length -gt $prev_size){
            $prev_size = $file.Length
            $wait = 5
            $count = 0
        } else {
            if($file.Length -eq $prev_size){
                $count += 1
                $wait = 15
            }
        }
    }Else{
        Write-Host "File Does Not Exist Yet..."
    }  
    Start-Sleep -s $wait


}Until($count -eq 7)
Write-Host "Tests completed."

#//Write to S3 bucket
```

Comment: **And adding -Wait to the Start-Process does not work.

Comment: `& $NUNIT_EXE $TESTING_DLL; if ($LastExitCode -eq 0) {...}`?

Answer (score 0):

**Ah... found my answer here:**
[Obtaining ExitCode using Start-Process and WaitForExit instead of -Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262231/obtaining-exitcode-using-start-process-and-waitforexit-instead-of-wait#16018287)

Need to wait for the Process and check the exit code. This worked well.