# Get return code from executing .Net program

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know how to get the return code from a .NET executable? I've written a program that has a static main method that returns an int and I can't seem to get this number when I run it from powershell. This is what I currently have:

```
&$executable $params
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

where `$executable` is the path to the executable and `$params` are the parameters passed to the executable.

However, `$LASTEXITCODE` is always 0. The program writes to the console via a Log4Net console appender so the above pipes the output to the console in PowerShell.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your PowerShell code. Please show the code of your .Net program.

Comment: I'm doing Environment.Exit(1) at the end of my static void Main() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(Start-Process -FilePath 'exe' -ArgumentList @() -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode
```

This will grab your exit code after execution completes.  You could even assign it to a variable and access the process members if you want.

Comment: Nope this didn't work. Exit code that comes back is still 0. My program is definitely setting the error code to 1 so I'm not sure why it always comes back at 0

Comment: @BigBytes If it's not capturing your exit code, your program apparently isn't returning non-zero.

Comment: (Start-Process -FilePath 'exe' -ArgumentList @() -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode did the trick

Comment: @BigBytes The `ArgumentList` is where an array of arguments would go, for example: `$Params`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like your executable doesn't return an exit code (i.e., `Environment.Exit()`) but instead outputs a result code (e.g., `Console.Write()`).

Try something like:

```
$ReturnValue = &$executable $params
Exit $ReturnValue
```

Comment: The executable has a static main method which returns an int which I assumed would be the equivalent of an exit code but maybe I need to try Enivronment.Exit() with an exit code. There is no Console.Write(). I will try what you suggested though and let you know if it works.

Comment: @BigBytes You may want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/how-do-i-specify-the-exit-code-of-a-console-application-in-net).  TLDR is either `Environment.Exit(value)` or `return value` should work.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm trying Environment.Exit(1) and using:-

        &$executable $params
        Exit $LastExitCode

But this doesn't work. It still thinks the return code is 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $ReturnValue = &$executable $params
Exit $ReturnValue

doesn't work either

Comment: @BigBytes Hm.  I've not seen that.  Try running it using one of the methods in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262275/696808).