# How to catch unexpected error running Liquibase in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, try-catch, liquibase, cicd

I have a small CI/CD script which is written in PowerShell, but I don't know how to stop it, if in the script I get unexpected error running Liquibase. All scripts in SQL and work (preconditions in place where I need to add), but I want to have more opportunity to control CI/CD script. Now, if the script gets the exception, it continues execution. The script updates some schemes and some of them has an influence on each other, so order is important.

```
#update first scheme - ETL (tables, global temp tables, packages)
.\liquibase update --defaults-file=import.properties

#how to stop this script, if I get unexpected error running Liquibase?

#update second scheme - data (only tables and roles for data)
.\liquibase update --defaults-file=data.properties
#update third scheme - views, tables and other for export data
.\liquibase update --defaults-file=export.properties
```

Comment: in fact, you need to track the exit code of the process
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262231/obtaining-exitcode-using-start-process-and-waitforexit-instead-of-wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$result = Start-Process -filepath 'path to liquibase' -ArgumentList "your liquibase arguments go here" -wait
if($result.ExitCode -ne 0){
  write-host 'something went wrong'
}
```

Comment: Work, but without "-wait $True", PowerShell write exception:"A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "True"", I used "-wait" and the script was run.

Comment: I passed $True to a switch, that was pretty pointless of me :p I adjusted the answer. Good luck with your script!